# Http client vs Mvc architecture

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, axios, fetch-api

We use axios,fetch-api.. for http requests such as get, post, etc. We can also get the same result using mvc. Please explain are they dependable to one another or i can use only mvc with out any http client.I am working on node mvc.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, in mvc applications, requests go through http requests. The difference between mvc and api-client applications is that the monolithic application running on mvc sends a request to itself again, while in api-client applications, a request is made to a different machine and port. If you run api-client in 2 different applications on the same machine, you will get a cors error for security reasons.

Comment: "*Basically, in mvc applications, requests go through http requests.* Not at all. A desktop application build in MVC would not be doing HTTP requests to itself. That would be silly.

Comment: "*If you run api-client in 2 different applications on the same machine, you will get a cors error for security reasons.*" that's also not true. The CORS configuration determines what is allowed to call and not. You could allow it for all localhost calls. Or just forbid it unless it comes from a certain domain and port. Or others.

Comment: @VLAZ can you please explain it further

Comment: i dont know how type  you want explain  but if you have time ,check this playlist https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1BztTYDF-QPgfvPouABKLwfTKxB6z7gk  video8-video14

Comment: thanks for your answer but i am on node mvc